# how can i use cast function and get correct result

Tags: sql

I get the wrong result by unsing  cast function.It should be simple but i can not figure out. need help.

```
SELECT        PRCo, Employee, LastName, FirstName, MidName, SortName, SSN, HireDate, DATEDIFF(month, HireDate, GETDATE()) / 12 AS Years,
               CAST((80/2080) as decimal(10, 5))
FROM           AAAA
```

`80/2080` column should be `0.038470` but it shows `0.00000` for all records

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

It's doing the division operation *before* the cast. When you divide two integers the result is also an integer, meaning any decimal portion is truncated. In this case, that leaves you with `0` for the result. Zero cast to `decimal(10,5)` is still just `0.00000`.

This should give a correct result:

```
CAST((80/2080.0) as decimal(10, 5))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I always forget this part. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(80 as decimal(10, 5))/2080
```